# Anime movie about a girl and her father who go to another world to try and revive her mother

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime, isekai

The movie takes place in another world and I can only describe two scenes that I'm certain are in the movie.

If I'm right, the topic of the movie is about a girl and her father who go to another world to try and revive her mother. The wish is granted by a sort of flying ship that is equal to a god in that world. The first scene would be that there are ruins and the girl is on a ruin and the Sun is slowly going down and there are monsters that only can be in the shadows trying to catch the girl. Another scene would be that the girl and the man are climbing a mountain to get to the ship.

I think the girl had black hair and the last time I watched this I think was like 5-6 years back.

Hope that someone knows the name. :D

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this? Also, what colour was the girl's hair?

Comment: I think she had black hair and the last time i watched it i think its like 5-6 years back

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Thx for the info